# How to reset the input pins after reading their state in PIC24?

Tags: io, pic, interrupt-handling

I am using the change notification interrupt to get information regarding the changes in the state of pins.

How do I reset the PIN values after reading it ?

Code for reading pin values of PORTB

```
x   = PORTB;
```

Comment: Many PICs have some variation of the INTF flag which is automatically enabled and must be disabled in software after every interrupt on portb. It prevents the interrupt from being fired multiple times. Can you tell us the exact model of PIC and compiler you are using, so we answer with more specific code?

Comment: Thank You!
I am using PIC24FJ64GA004 for the project and using XC16.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you mean with "reset PIN values" but... If the pins are configured to be inputs (as in the case of reading), you are not supposed to be able to reset the pin values as they are controlled externally.

Anyway, a simple PORTB = 0; should turn all pins off (reset?) if configured as outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is how to reset the change notification mechanism.
The pic has an internal buffer which is set equal to the the port pins.  An interrupt change notification is generated by exclusive-or'ing this buffer with the port pins.
Reading the port sets the value of the internal buffer equal to the current state of the port pins.  Now the port is ready again to fire a change notification interrupt.

In summary reading the port is sufficient to reset the change notification mechanism.  However you must also clear the change notification interrupt flag.